# getting around coding fonts for iphone 4 and iphone 3

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have an app initially designed on iPhone 3.2.

To design for iPhone 4 I know the images need to be of double size and postfixed with @2x.

How do I get around the font blurring issue. Now all the text appears blurred and pixelated when seen on iphone 4 or the iPad.

Any suggestions to work around the code for iPad and iPhone 4?

Edit: I know I can check the OS version ([UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]) but after that what?

Answer (score 0):

I want to inform u that font is set according to device resolution so we have not set separate for iphone-4/4s.

If u get problem like that,so make ensure that, blurred text is not part of image.

Comment: what about iphone 3 to iphone 4? in Ipad all the text comes blurred in UIlabel

Comment: Sorry dear,but it not possible.i am sure that your label is part of image.